# Can't retrieve data from array with ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm creating an app using Ionic2 and I'm trying to print a list of songs titles from an array.
I have these 2 files, but I can't get the list of songs, I don't even get errors and warnings.

**songlist.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/songlist/songlist.html',
})

export class Songlist {
    songs
    test
    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.songs = ['Song 1','song 2','song 3'];
        this.test = "this is a test";
    }
}
```

**songlist.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Ionic 2 Application</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
{{test}} // "this is a test" is correctly printed
  <ion-list class="messageList">
     <ion-item *ngFor="let item of songs">{{item}}</ion-item>  
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Do you even get `Ionic 2 Application` text when you run the app?

Comment: yes, I can see Ionic 2 Application text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `songs` array is not properly declared:

```
export class Songlist {
    private songs: Array<string>; // <- That's how the array should be declared

    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.songs = ['Song 1','song 2','song 3'];
    }
}
```

Comment: `songs:Array<string>;test:string;`

Comment: If I inspect ion-list element in google chrome console I see this text: <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null
}-->

Comment: The `songs` array should be public for the template to use it.  Remove the `private` keyword from the declaration.

Comment: @Brad That's not true. It could be `private` or `public`, but it works in both ways.